# How to escape "." with sed or grep?

Tags: command-line, bash, grep, sed

I have `file` with

```
denm.xyz
denm.abc
denm.def
denm_xyz
denm_abc
denm_def
```

I want to extract the ones with `.` in it.

I tried

```
grep "denm\.*" file
grep 'denm\.*' file

sed "/denm\.*/p" file
sed '/denm\.*/p' file
```

These things are matching everything in the `file`

However using `awk`

```
awk '/denm\./' file
```

worked!!

How do I do same using `grep` or `sed`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You were close, you just need to remove `*` which means zero or more match of the preceding token, `.` in this case. As a result the `demn_` is also being showed in the result as it matched the condition of zero `.`.

So you can do:

```
grep 'denm\.' file.txt
```

Similarly in `sed`:

```
sed -n '/denm\./p' file.txt
```

Note that you have missed the `-n` option of `sed`, without it `sed` will print all the lines too.

There are also so many level of precision can be added to get exactly what you want in complex cases but take it as a start.

**Example:**

```
% grep 'denm\.' file.txt
denm.xyz
denm.abc
denm.def

% sed -n '/denm\./p' file.txt
denm.xyz
denm.abc
denm.def
```

Comment: This works!!. How about `sed`. The same is not working with it

Comment: @RamanaReddy You have missed the `-n` option of `sed` ..check my edits..

Comment: you may also use char class  `[]` for escaping, like `[.]`

Answer (score 7):

`\.*` means "any number of occurrences of the character `.`", including zero. Since your underscored filenames start with `denm` followed by zero occurrences of the character `.`, they are matched. `grep "denm\." file` will work.

Comment: Well this works. How about `sed`

Answer (score 3):

If all you need are the lines that have a `.` in them, used grep with fixed strings instead of regular expressions:

```
grep -F . file
```

From [`man grep`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/grep.1.html):

```
-F, --fixed-strings
      Interpret PATTERN as a  list  of  fixed  strings,  separated  by
      newlines,  any  of  which is to be matched.  (-F is specified by
      POSIX.)
```

With fixed strings, all regular expression special characters lose their meaning.

`sed` does not have a corresponding option.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to use brackets instead of backslashes for escaping:

```
egrep "denm[.].*" file
sed -r 's/denm[.]/.../'
```

This saves me the effort of thinking if and how I should escape the backslashes. (The final `.*` is redundant here.)

Comment: note that some may misunderstand this like `[+.]` used for escaping `+` and `.` but what it does it matches only one character whether it may be `+` or `.`